# How to change the source branch for existing merge request in gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ce

I have a merge request and a source branch is already bound to it. Now I pushed another branch and want to change the merge request to be point to the new branch. Is that possible with gitlab-ce? If yes, how?

In essence, I want to use "Fast-forward merge" as merge method without being forced to force-push to the source branch.

Comment: Why do you want (need?) to use the same Merge request? Can't you drop the old one and create a new one with the branch you want?

Comment: Because then, I loose the discussion, and have to copy-paste the descriptions etc.

Comment: Fair enough, non-technical but valid reason.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, regarding https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/47020 this is unfortunately not possible. The statement is from last year, but it seems that there were no changes in supporting this for now.

To not lose the discussion completely, you can link the old MR in the new MR. With that you at least have some indirect relation to the discussion.

Comment: i guess its not the answer i hoped for, but actually the correct answer... so... yes

Comment: man there is a handful of gitlab annoyances that make zero sense, add this to the list...